# UIPageViewController sets view controller out of the screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipageviewcontroller

I'm trying to add a UIPageViewController to my App using following code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSArray *viewControllers = @[page0,
                        page1,
                        page2];

    self.pageController = [[UIPageViewController alloc] initWithTransitionStyle:UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyleScroll
                                                          navigationOrientation:UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientationHorizontal
                                                                        options:nil];
    self.pageController.dataSource = self;
    self.pageController.view.frame = self.view.frame;
    [self.pageController setViewControllers:@[[viewControllers firstObject]]
                                  direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward
                                   animated:NO
                                 completion:nil];
    [self.pageController willMoveToParentViewController:self];
    [self addChildViewController:self.pageController];
    [self.view addSubview:self.pageController.view];
    [self.pageController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
}
```

Then problem is that when I run the application, using the Simulator or a physical device, I get a empty screen. If I try to swipe the views I can see that the page that I actually added to the viewControllers array is already there but outside of the screen. Making some debugging with SparkInspector, I can see that the view is actually there but with an offset with the same value equal to the screen width.
I also have implemented the DataSource for the UIPageViewController. Here are the implementation of the delegated methods:

```
- (NSInteger) presentationCountForPageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController {
    return 3;
}

- (NSInteger) presentationIndexForPageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController {
    return 0;
}

- (UIViewController *) pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {

    if (viewController == nil) {
        return [viewControllers firstObject];
    }

    NSUInteger index = [viewControllers indexOfObject:viewController];
//    NSParameterAssert(index != NSNotFound);

    index++;

    if (index == viewControllers.count) {
        return nil;
    }

    return [viewControllers objectAtIndex:index];
}

- (UIViewController *) pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerBeforeViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {

    if (viewController == nil) {
        return [viewControllers firstObject];
    }

    NSUInteger index = [viewControllers indexOfObject:viewController];

    if (index == 0) {
        return nil;
    }
    index--;
    return [viewControllers objectAtIndex:index];
}
```

I cannot see why the App is offsetting the view controllers, so any advice will be very helpful.

Comment: Well the first thing I would try would be to not set the page view controller's view's frame equal to its superview's frame. I would set it to its bounds instead. Not sure if this will fix the problem though.

Comment: Hi drbeardface, thanks for the suggestion. But I already try that approach with same results. I forgot to mention that I'm using RESideMenu and I'm not sure if it could affect. I've been checking the issues on their site but I see nothing that may affect

Comment: I found the source of the problem. It has to do with the constraints of the views and the offset that is set in the view controller once it's added to the uipageviewcontroller. I'll keep researching on this, and post the solution if I'm able to find it.

Comment: Although I solved the problem by recreating the views of each page I think that is not a solution for this question since I did find the source of the error. If anyone may have an idea for the reason it will be very welcomed.

Comment: I had the same problem and only recreating the XIB of the content view controller helped. The XIB that had the problem contained views that where copied from another XIB. I guess Xcode did messed something up in that process.